# onResume() of previous fragment getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume

In my app there is one `Activity` and three `fragments` say A,B,C.I add them one upon each other. 
I don't load the fragment `A` in `backstack`, but on click of list view item, I load the other two in backstack. Now my issue and funny part is,while `onBackPressed()` none of the callback methods (`onResume(),onStart()`) of any fragment gets called, but if I lock the phone and resume my activity,and I am on fragment C,onResume of all the previous fragments A and B gets called.In `onResume()` I have called an api,and all the checks get failed

```
if(getFragmentManager()!=null && activity!=null) {
      DashboardFragment currentFragment = (DashboardFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
      if(currentFragment.isVisible() && isAdded() && isVisible() && getUserVisibleHint()) {
       //callApi;
       }
}
```

none of the methods like isvisible() and so on return correct values and methods like

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

are not getting called. So how do I ensure I call the api only when the fragment is visible.

Comment: Are you using `add` or `replace` when adding these fragments into the Activity's view?

Comment: @mwieczorek I am using add

Comment: add or replace not make any difference in it

Comment: is your fragment c onResume() called or not ?

Comment: @jiteshmohite yes, it is,but I want to ensure that onResume of A is not called when I am on c

Comment: A's `onResume()` method won't be called unless it's brought back into view if B or C is destroyed or C is nested within A.

Comment: It is not getting called even on backPress , even if I go back from C to B and B to A. But it is getting called when phone comes alive from locked state,even if I am on fragment C.

Comment: To clarify, are all these fragments being loaded into the same view (R.id.container)? Just trying to get a picture of your flow.

Comment: @mwieczorek Yes you are correct,in same container.

Comment: Use `replace()` instead of `add()` when adding B and C to that view (add A with `add()`). No sense in having A using up memory when not visible.

Answer (score 0):

The code I use to load data from an API only after the fragment becomes visible to the user is:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        // API call
    }
}
```

Not quite clear on why you're calling your `DashboardFragment` from the others if they're not nested.

You could, of course, add the API logic to the `onResume()` method. Unless your fragments are in a ViewPager, they will be visible to the user when `onResume()` is called.

Comment: I am not calling DashboardFragment , DashboardFragment is A fragment, but when the phone comes alive and even if I am on Fragment C the onResume of DashBoardFragment is also getting called.

Comment: Unless you need A in memory for some reason while B or C is active, you should use `replace`. That would solve the issue of anything in A being called when you don't want it to.

Comment: Also the method you mentioned is not getting called when fragment is loaded

Comment: `getUserVisibleHint()` is called before `onCreate()` if I remember correctly.

Comment: That should be `setUserVisibleHint()` above, and it is called before onCreate.